# Finding position of viewport in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I need to find the position of the top left corner of the viewport in Selenium. I know we can use drive_get_window_position() to get the window position, but I need just the position of the part that renders. Is that possible?

The use case is that I am attempting to use Selenium to get the coordinates of an element, and need to move the cursor to it. Since Selenium only moves the virtual mouse and not the visible cursor, I am using pyautogui to move the cursor to absolute coordinates.

However because the browser position affects where the absolute coordinates should be, I need to know where the viewport is so I can offset appropriately. Using the get_window_position() works for x coordinates but not y coordinates due to the various menus and toolbars.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you need to achieve. I am assuming you need to hover... and I don't believe you need pyAutoGUI for this task. ```TouchAction``` could be utilize. If that is what you need and provide a link and manual step.. I can look into this.. Don't know about the viewport tho.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into TouchAction. I'm not trying to achieve a specific task right now, I'm building tools to make my life easier in the future and since a lot of what I'm doing involves working both with browsers as well as other applications, I need to be able to control the cursor outside of Selenium.

So being able to easily translate between where an element is in the browser and what the absolute coordinates are will help me integrate other applications with my web automation.

Answer (score 0):

> **location_once_scrolled_into_view¶**
>
> THIS PROPERTY MAY CHANGE WITHOUT WARNING. Use this to discover where
> on the screen an element is so that we can click it. This method
> should cause the element to be scrolled into view.

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement

Returns the top lefthand corner location on the screen, or None if the element is not visible.

**Eg:**

```
e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html')
print(e.location_once_scrolled_into_view)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting an error "no such element: Unable to locate element."

Am I supposed to replace the xpath with something else? I'm on Windows if that makes a difference.

Comment: @TheNomadicAspie what element are you trying ? The one in answer is just an example replace the xpaht with your context

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. I'm not attempting to find the location of an xpath, I'm attempting to locate the absolute coordinates of the top left corner of the viewport when using a Chrome browser with Selenium.

Comment: View port. Left corner is always 0'0 ,

Comment: Selenium to get the coordinates of an element , for that use this code . It will show cordinate of the element when it is scrolled into view .

Comment: So replace the e with the element you are trying

Comment: I need to be able to get the absolute coordinates (For the whole screen) of the viewport of the browser window. So I need to for example use a non-Selenium based module to find the viewpoint of the Selenium browser. Am I explaining the clearly? I apologize if not.

Comment: @TheNomadicAspie just use xpath as //html

Comment: Updated the answer youvcsn try //body also